# «Всё, точка». Как оформить

Tags: пунктуация

«Всё, точка.» Как оформить правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно точку из кавычек вытащить: никогда точка не ставится перед закрывающими кавычками (в русском).

«Всё, точка».

Answer (score 0):

Нужно точку в конце поставить, чтобы пунктуация не противоречила содержанию.

Comment: ну само собой. Спасибо